# Url rewrite base on query IIS asp.net

Tags: asp.net, url-rewriting

I'm doing this for the first time need help.  How to make code with url rewrite 2.0  to url rewrite base on query.

I need to:

```
www.Example/Ekonomija/Ekonomija.aspx?Ekonomija=something
```

to be

```
www.Example/Ekonomija/something
```

and

```
www.Example/Test2/Test2.aspx?Test2=something
```

to be

```
www.Example/Test2/something
```

and

```
www.Example/Test3/Test3.aspx?Test3=something
```

to be

```
www.Example/Test3/something
```

and so on ....

**Need solution with url rewrite: 2.0**

**EDITED**
I try.... but I have problem first role working good but second no, probably query string not not accurately done, don't know.

```
<rule name="RedirectUserFriendlyURL1" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^Ekonomija/Ekonomija\.aspx$" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{REQUEST_METHOD}" pattern="^POST$" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="^([^=&amp;]+)=([^=&amp;]+)$" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="{C:1}/{C:2}" appendQueryString="false" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="RewriteUserFriendlyURL1" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="Ekonomija/Ekonomija.aspx?{R:1}={R:2}" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="RedirectUserFriendlyURL2" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^Test2/Test2\.aspx$" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{REQUEST_METHOD}" pattern="^POST$" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="^([^=&amp;]+)=([^=&amp;]+)$" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="{C:1}/{C:2}" appendQueryString="false" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="RewriteUserFriendlyURL2" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="Test2/Test2.aspx?{R:1}={R:2}" />
            </rule>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might work with the first one but it will never work with the second.
Why?

Because you have two rules matching exactly the same conditions: `RewriteUserFriendlyURL1` and `RewriteUserFriendlyURL2`

In this case, the second one is never executed because it is processed in order and the first one will always take over.

Anyway, I have tried to simplify your rules as following:

```
<rule name="Redirect rule" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^(Ekonomija/Ekonomija|Test2/Test2)\.aspx$" />
    <conditions>                                                        
        <add input="{REQUEST_METHOD}" pattern="^POST$" negate="true" />
        <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="^(\w+)=(\w+)$" />
    </conditions>                                            
    <action type="Redirect" url="{C:1}/{C:2}" appendQueryString="false" />
</rule>
<rule name="Rewrite rule" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^(Ekonomija|Test2)/(\w+)$" /> 
    <conditions>
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}/{R:1}.aspx?{R:1}={R:2}" />
</rule>
```

The redirect is only working when

- the requested url is either `Ekonomija/Ekonomija.aspx` or `Test2/Test2.aspx`
- the method used to access the url was not `POST`
- the query string was only one alphanumeric sequence followed by an equal sign (`=`) followed by a second alphanumeric sequence

In this case, we redirect using the back references from the query string (`first sequence/second sequence`).

We then have the rewrite rule working when

- the requested url starts with `Ekonomija` or `Test2`, is followed by a slash (`/`) and contains one or more alphanumeric character(s) after
- the requested url doesn't match the path to file or a directory on the server

In this case, we rewrite using the back references from the requested url.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I try these solution but get error" HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found"

Comment: I found why not code working, and is not a problem in the code but in my  query it contains "ž,š,ć, _, -"....Thank you and I'm sorry I'm asking this more, but can you help me to rewrite regular expression to mach with that words, really do not understand that area. thank you

Comment: In these case you can replace the `[A-z0-9]` with `\w` so for example `pattern="^([A-z0-9]+)=([A-z0-9]+)$"` becomes `pattern="^(\w+)=(\w+)$"`. I will edit my answer.

Comment: That's it, thank you, you saved me, I was already prepared to learn regular expression, but managed to postpone it for another time, hate regular expression :D